# SQL join with comparison operator problem

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I m having a very tricky SQL question, maybe the trickiest I have had
suppose I have one table below

called table_1

| Date | spend |
| --- | --- |
| Oct. 20 | 50 |
| Oct. 19 | 40 |
| Oct. 18 | 50 |
| Oct. 17 | 60 |
| Oct. 16 | 50 |

and now I need another table that sums up all the spend that I have made, before and include the every date.   like to show every I have spend so far for each date.

And for each of the date.

Below is the table that I want compute

called table_2

| Date | spent |
| --- | --- |
| Oct. 20 | 250 ( sum of all the spend before and includes Oct.20) |
| Oct. 19 | 200 ( sum of all the spend before and includes Oct.19) |
| Oct. 18 | 160 ( sum of all the spend before and includes Oct.18) |
| Oct. 17 | 110 ( sum of all the spend before and includes Oct.17) |
| Oct. 16 | 50 ( sum of all the spend before and includes Oct.16) |

I have tried with table_1 left join itself with left join on date_1 <= date_2.

does not work.

Could someone please give me a hint for it?

Answer (score 1):

You want a running total. You get this with the windw function `SUM OVER`.

```
select date, sum(spend) over(order by date) as sum_spent 
from mytable
order by date desc;
```

And if you should suffer from having to use an old MySQL version that doesn't support window functions yet, here is an old-fashioned alternative:

```
select 
  date, 
  (select sum(spend) from mytable t2 where t2.date <= t.date) as sum_spent 
from mytable t
order by date desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Supplementary to Thorsten Kettner's answer, `LEFT JOIN` you've made attempt also works

```
SELECT a.date, SUM(b.spend)
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_1 b ON a.date >= b.date
GROUP BY a.date
```